# Configure WCF to ignore authentication requirements inside IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-7

Scenario:

1. Two websites (example.com, admin.example.com) that share the same wwwroot folder.
2. example.com allows only anonymous access
3. admin.example.com allows only windows authentication.
4. /Service/Awesome.svc returns a json object

Accessing the Awesome service using example.com works, while admin.example.com throws a NotSupportedException; *"Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service."*

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <services>
    <service name="WcfServices.AwesomeService"
             behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="WcfServices.IAwesomeService" 
                behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How do I configure WCF to ignore the authentication requirement? I want the same behavior as if this were a web service or handler, just execute and return the awesome json object.

Comment: Self-host your WCF service for full control.... Hosting in IIS is just a kludge....

Comment: And which of these sites is hosting the service?

Comment: This is just one of many services, in one giant kludge-like site. Self-hosting would be yet another part in a giant maintenance nightmare. Would be nice if it were possible with some configuration settings.

Comment: Both sites hosts the service; http://example.com/Service/Awesome.svc and http://admin.example.com/Service/Awesome.svc

Comment: In such case example.com sould provide anonymous access.

Comment: example.com is providing anonymous access, but paths are relative (and sometimes the admin site isn't a subdomain), so scripts reference /Service/Awesome.svc, and both sites should be able to answer. The user is already browsing the site, and has all permissions needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two copies of the service, one under the website example.com and the other under admin.example.com.  If admin.example.com needs IIS integrated (challenge/response) authentication then you're WCF service binding needs to be in Transport mode because IIS requires all admin.example.com resources to be Windows authentication.  Try this configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

If this doesn't work for you, you may want to try hosting the services in their own virtual directy so they are not at the mercy of what the website needs for security.

Good Luck.

Comment: The problem with this being that it would affect both sites (since they share same configuration files), thus disabling access to the service from the anonymous site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck here. Give AWesome.svc anonymous access, and give anon access a user account that has no access to sensitive resources.